# Printing result of calculation with 1 decimal number

Tags: python, map-projections

As a beginner in Python and I stumbled upon a seemingly simple code that I can't make to work.

I'm trying to print an output of calculation with 1 decimal number, this is one of the versions of the code I tried. I also tried using `format(x/s, '.1f')`, but neither of those worked.

There is part of my code:

```
for v in range(n):
    #It will repeat the calculation the many times its defined in n input
    x = R*(v*n)
    if x/s*100<100:
        print("meridian will be", '%.1f' % x/s*100, "cm from center")
    else x/s*100>100:
        print("meridian will be - cm from center")
```

Using `'%.1f'` seems to have no effect, is the syntax wrong? I'm really not sure...

Comment: Try replacing `% x/s*100` by `% (x/s*100)`

Comment: you can get plenty of inspiration from [this already existent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Comment: Now it works perfectly, thanks.
Edit: yes I searched in existing answers and tried to copy it from there, but example was a bit different. There was no need to use the () "bracket" in other examples.

Comment: Maybe https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence will help.